# Allow an user to be both "User" and "Admin" roles

Tags: asp.net, security, authorization, roles

I am having a problem and would like to know if someone has a suggestion. On a site I am developing, I was using Asp.net Simple Membership but now I am migrating to Asp.net Identity 2. I have 2 roles:  "User" and "Admin". The admin can do admin stuf, configuration, database management, etc. But cannot do "user things". So, the admin is not a "super user" - it only has different function.

The problem I am facing is that the unique identifier for the user is their email. So, if someone wants to use the system all by himself he has to create 2 accounts (one admin and one user), so he has to have 2 emails. This is a problem. I could easily add both "user" and "admin" roles to that users but that would make the system harder to use for the "user" role and I would like to avoid this.

I use roles to authorize routes on the server (MVC and web api) and to basic (like hide elements) things on the UI (SPA), so, it is already part of the system - but I am willing to change it, if necessary.

I was thinking in doing something like this:

When the user is configured to be a administrator, every time he log on, I ask if he want to be an admin or user on this session.
If he choose "user", I set a user role for him and log in.
If he choose "admin", I set a "admin" role for him and log in.

What do you think about that? Does someone have a better idea? This feels like a hack and hacks do not go well with security :/

I see a problem with that - Sometimes I need to send emails to admins (when they are offline). With this, I cannot rely on the UserRole table only, will always have to check the User.IsAdministrator flag too. It is not a big problem but add a small complexity to things.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use roles for this. A user can be a member of several roles at once, so you can have a user that is a member of the 'user' roles, a user that is a member of the 'admin' role or a user that is a member of both the 'user' and 'admin' roles.

You have already suggested this idea and this is how I would do it, if you then wanted to control what they could see (so that an 'admin' member could only see stuff that normally a 'user' role user can see) then you could have a drop down on any form (or put it on your master page) that allows the user to turn the admin stuff on and off, you can then remember their selecting in the session object and refer to that each time the page loads. e.g.

```
  if user.IsInRole("Admin") and IsNothing(Session("HideAdmin")) Then
       'Show Admin Stuff
  End If
```

Or somthing similar.

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem is solved at DataBase Design time not at development time. You have few choice the best I see is create a Third user who will have both rights.